# Convert the following expression w.r.t to the whole dataset instead of element of the dataset?

Tags: svm, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, lagrange-multipliers

I am in the process of expressing the w in LSSVM with data points and constants. After I resolve the KKT conditions for the LSSVM I got
$$w = \sum ^N _{i=1} \alpha_i x_i$$
Is it possible to convert the x_i in this expression to big X (X is the whole dataset, a matrix)? The "alpha" in this expression is the Lagrange multiplier and the "xi" is the element of the dataset(a datapoint, it can be a vector or a single element).
I tried using trace of matrices but it didn't take me very far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. We have:

$$ w = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i=\alpha_1 x_1+ \alpha_2 x_2 + ... + \alpha_n x_n$$

Then, if we define:
$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1^T\\
x_2^T\\
\vdots\\
x_n^T
\end{pmatrix} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1\\
\alpha_2\\
\vdots\\
\alpha_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

Where each $x_i$ is a m-dimensional vector ($\text{size}(x_i)=m\times 1\rightarrow \text{size}(X)=n\times m)$). And each $\alpha_i$ is a scalar.

We can obtain $w$ by:
$$ w =X^T\alpha$$

Where $w$ is a m-dimensional vector as well as each datapoint $x_i$.

---

**Simple example:**

Let's suppose we have the next two datapoints $x_1$ and $x_2$:

$$x_1=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
\end{pmatrix}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x_2=\begin{pmatrix}
c\\
d\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, the data matrix is given by:

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^T\\
x_2^T\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Further, suppose we have that $\alpha_1=e$ and $\alpha_2=f$, then:
$$\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1\\
\alpha_2\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
e\\
f\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, using the summatory:
$$ w = \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i= e\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
\end{pmatrix}+f\begin{pmatrix}
c\\
d\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And if we use the matrix form:

$$ w = X^T\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
e\\
f\\
\end{pmatrix}=e\begin{pmatrix}
a\\
b\\
\end{pmatrix}+f\begin{pmatrix}
c\\
d\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Is it valid that $$w=\alpha^T X$$ can also be formulated as $$w = \sum ^N _{i=1} \alpha_i x_i$$? In this case the resulting dimension of w would be different?  I am a bit confused about this..

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent. If you want, you can try to do a simple example by hand and check it.

Comment: This is interesting, thank you for the answers!

Comment: I edited the answer with a simple example so you can ckeck it

Comment: With the above example, if I use $w=\alpha^T X$ I would get an answer with a different dimension. Mathematically $(\alpha^T X) = (X^T \alpha)^T$ resulting essentially different $w$, how could both of them be valid conversions from $\sum^N_{i=1}\alpha_i x_i$, What did I miss?

Comment: Ah sorry, in your first comment I read $X^T\alpha$ instead of $\alpha^TX$. If you do $\alpha^TX$ then we obtain $w^T$,  as you have just correctly said ($w^T=(X^T\alpha)^T$). But of course, it would be the same $w$, just transposed.